# Will they send offer letter within 15th April

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

In this fall 2016 I have applied  for graduate admission (PhD, Physics) few universities and I have received an admit from one of them. The university gave me a deadline (April 15)  to accept or decline the offer.

On the other hand, I emailed the other few universities(my priority university selection where I would love to join.) to know my application status.  They have put me on a waiting-list.

What is the possibility of these university that they will send another round offer letters within the 15th April ?

Comment: We cannot answer that. You should contact the other universities to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is certainly a possibility that you will get moved from the wait list to acceptance before April 15th, but there is absolutely no guarantee or requirement of further contact. By "possibility", I mean this happens to students every year and it isn't particularly unusual - but I also mean that this only happens to a minority of students, and is hard to predict due to the nature of statistics and small numbers per program. Some programs might admit 2 students and both admitted students accept, while others might admit 20 yet go 2+ full rounds of wait list contacts before admission decisions are officially finished.

The general advice in the US is that you are safe to wait until close to that April 15th deadline for acceptance if you are not certain that's where you want to go, even if you are just holding out to see if any wait listed programs might accept you. Waiting past that deadline is risky unless you request and obtain an extension, as programs are well within their rights to rescind their offers and move on to their own wait list after the dead line.

Answer (score 1):

having served on an admissions committee and observed this from inside, sometimes a program will keep students waitlisted until very shortly before april 15.  as it continues to get closer you can politely express enthusiasm and inquire, although you don't want to be too pushy.  offers are often sent out on a rolling basis for a variety of reasons, such as higher priority recruits declining offers.  you can safely hold out until the 14th or 15th before you make a decision, but do follow up one last time with your first choice before accepting anything.  good luck.